# How to grant user access the page

Tags: permissions

Is there any plugin where i can create a page and grant permission for specific user and that user should be able to see the pages which are accessible for him/her? or is there a way i can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [User Specific Content](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-specific-content) Plugin

Where you can set user by role, user name etc. for a page & post.

Hope this will helps you.